# Git hangs on commit from atom

Tags: git, atom-editor

This appears to be specifically related to Atom with Git.

I can successfully change my .gitconfig using either direct editing or by entering the git command:

```
$ git config --global core.editor "<editor> -w"
```

When editor is emacs or gedit, I have the experience one would expect. Git waits for a commit message to be written, and when the editor is done, git reads the commit message and finishes the commit.

When I set Atom as the editor, Git launches Atom, but then keeps waiting after I've saved (bad) and quit (worse). I'm left with Git in a wait state and have to CTRL-C my way out of it. This leaves me in an odd state where COMMIT_EDITMSG has been written to .git, but Git can't/won't see it.

Fedora 23. Atom 1.40.1. Git 2.5.5

Your thoughts (other than that I should probably stop running antique software)?